# sql how to take a number and display it 1 of 2, 2 of 2

Tags: sql, oracle

Having trouble finding anything on this or if anyone can direct me to a question already asked, that would be great.

Table Customer

```
ORDER,      QTY_ORDER  
A1234 ,        5
```

Select Output

```
ORDER,          QTY_ORDER  
A1234,            1 OF 5  
A1234,            2 OF 5  
A1234,            3 OF 5  
A1234,            4 OF 5  
A1234,            5 OF 5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: using `ORDER` as a column name is a **terrible** idea.

(I used `order_id` as the column name instead, to make things easier)

```
with order_rows as (
   select distinct c.order_id, level as lvl, c.qty_order
   from customer c
   connect by level <= c.qty_order
)
select r.order_id, to_char(r.lvl)||' of '||r.qty_order
from order_rows r
order by order_id, lvl;
```

But that is not going to be very efficient.

SQLFiddle Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3cdc1/2

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for MS SQL Server that will work for any number of orders. I assumed the QTY_ORDER to be max 2 characters. In case more is needed, increase the size of `char(2)`  to fit your needs.

```
DECLARE @counter int; DECLARE @order varchar(10); DECLARE @qty int; 
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

SELECT @sql = '';
SELECT @order = MIN([ORDER]) FROM Customer;
WHILE @order IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @counter = 1;
    SELECT @qty = QTY_ORDER FROM Customer WHERE [ORDER] = @order;
    WHILE @counter  @order;
END

SELECT @sql = SUBSTRING(@sql,1, LEN(@sql) - 6);
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Output:

```
Order QTY_ORDER
----- ---------
A1234 1  of 5 
A1234 2  of 5 
A1234 3  of 5 
A1234 4  of 5 
A1234 5  of 5
```

Edit: 
Hmm. Didn't see the Oracle tag. My mistake.

Comment: I added the Oracle tag. Before that it was tagged with `plsql` (which is Oracle's stored procedure language) - but as the question is not about writing a stored procedure I removed it.